# How to write .htaccess file to get everything after slash as parameter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a URL i.e "www.mysite.com". I want to send parameters via url in following ways:

```
www.mysite.com/count
www.mysite.com/search_caption?query=huha
www.mysite.com/page=1
www.mysite.com/search_caption?query=huha&page=1
```

In each of these cases I want to load index.php page with parameters as follows for each case:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST) results into [count]
var_dump($_REQUEST) results into [query="huha"]
var_dump($_REQUEST) results into [page=1]
var_dump($_REQUEST) results into [query="huha",page=1]
```

How do I write .htaccess file to achieve this?

I am using this code but it is capturing only params after "?" and not everything after first slash

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?{REQUEST_FILENAME}=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Why not? Your question is clearly answered in there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I read and write this Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?{REQUEST_FILENAME}=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L], but its not working

Comment: @arkascha please suggest me solution I have searched on many websites but I am not finding like I need

Comment: Please do not add details or code to comments here. It is not readable. Please use the `edit` button right below your question and add details to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha question updated

Comment: Could you explain the first example `www.mysite.com/count`? It appears to follow a different logic than the rest...

Comment: Also `www.mysite.com/page=1` is not actually a valid URL, It violates the URL syntax.

Comment: Count is a parameter which is when send to the page then page return total number of the rows in the database table

Comment: www.mysite.com/page=1 by this I meant to to send a variable 'page' with value 1

Comment: I know what is meant in both cases, but still it is odd: the first would define a query argument with _key_ `count` and an empty value, is that _really_ what you want? the second one still violates the URL syntax, logical and valid would be `www.mysite.com/page/1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should get close, though you really should think about those strange URL patterns instead of trying to fix them afterwards with rewriting...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^count index.php?count=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Some notes:

- the first three RewriteRules are exceptions necessary because your given requests do not follow a sane and common pattern. They appear somewhat chaotically chosen.
- this certainly is not free of issues, I did not test it, only typed it down.
- this assumes the "page" example to be requested like as discussed in the comments.
- `index.php` actually has to exist as a file, otherwise this will result in a rewrite loop

Given all that these rewritings should happen:

```
www.mysite.com/count => index.php?count=1
www.mysite.com/search_caption?query=huha => index.php?query=huha
www.mysite.com/page/1 => index.php?page=1
www.mysite.com/search_caption?query=huha&page=1 => index.php?query=huha&page=1
```

Also note that the rules above are written for `.htaccess` style files. To be used as normal rules, so inside the http servers host configuration, they would have to be written slightly different. You should only use `.htaccess` style files if you really, really have to, so if you have no access to the configuration files. You should always try to avoid those files if somehow possible. They are notoriously error prone, hard to setup and debug and *really* slow the server down. So if you have access to the http server configuration, then defines such rules in there instead.

Comment: Working. how to access `$_GET` parameter?

Comment: @ThusithaWickramasinghe Sorry, I do not really understand your question... A http GET parameter is accessed by the superglobal `$_GET` variable in php, sure. So what _is_ your question?